# SQL: Found formula to generate dates, just trying to understand it

Tags: mysql, sql

So this formula, I've now seen it in multiple answers to the question of how to generate a list of dates quickly and efficiently, without loops and whatnot. The formula works, I've copied it, tested it, played with it, etc. The thing is, I just do not understand the math behind it. I hate using things I don't understand, I feel like I'm A) cheating, and B) setting myself up for problems later on.

Anyway, here's the formula I'm talking about:

```
set @start_date = '2015-9-20';
set @end_date = '2016-9-20';

select @start_date + interval ((a.a) + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) day as this_date
from 
(select 0 as a
union all select 1
union all select 2
union all select 3
union all select 4
union all select 5
union all select 6
union all select 7
union all select 8
union all select 9) as a cross join
(select 0 as a
union all select 1
union all select 2
union all select 3
union all select 4
union all select 5
union all select 6
union all select 7
union all select 8
union all select 9) as b cross join
(select 0 as a
union all select 1
union all select 2
union all select 3
union all select 4
union all select 5
union all select 6
union all select 7
union all select 8
union all select 9) as c;
```

QUICK NOTE: the start_date/end_date stuff is just for me. I'm ultimately going to turn this into a procedure that uses those two values to generate the date range, the values here are just test values as I work this out.

So, let's start with the part I do understand, and then move on to everything else.

1) The unions are essentially creating 3 tables of 10 rows, with the integer values 0-9.

2) The 3 tables are being joined together without specifying a where clause, meaning its a cartesian join and the number of rows is being increased exponentially (10 x 10 x 10 = 1000).

3) The date value is being incremented by an interval of days equal to the values within the parenthesis next to the INTERVAL statement.

4) The pattern of the math mirrors the cartesian join. The first table has each value multiplied by 1, the second by 10, the third by 100.

WHAT I DON'T UNDERSTAND: the math itself. Somehow, by adding those numbers together, the outcome is an interval that ultimately increments the value of the date by 1000 days. I just really want to understand why this works, beyond just the pattern but the actual mathematical, programatic reason why this works.

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: But your query doesnt use `@enddate`

Comment: Not yet. It will, when I parse the list of generated dates to narrow it down to what I want. The end date stuff is my own addition, the formula is the part I'm trying to understand before I take that last step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is generate a range between two dates.

You usually could use a loop `for` or `while` but that doesnt work with a plain select and you will need a store procedure.

As you realize the select generate number from 0 to 999.

So you can generate almost 3 years of dates. What you get is:

```
@start_date + 1 day
@start_date + 2 days
@start_date + 3 days
...
@start_date +  999 days
```

But your query miss the where clausule

```
WHERE @start_date + interval ((a.a) + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) <= @end_date
```

Imagine you want create hours range, you will need add another table to increase range to `0.. 9999` and set interval to `hours`

```
DATE_ADD(@start_date, INTERVAL (a.a) + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a) + (1000 * d.a) HOUR)
```

to get:

```
@start_date + 1 hour
@start_date + 2 hours
@start_date + 3 hours
...
@start_date +  9999 hours
```

**ADDITIONAL EXPLAIN**

All the union create a derivated table. That code is equivalent to you create a table with 1000 rows and do a select from that.

```
SELECT *
FROM table1000

1000 rows return
```

Then you use each value on that table with the constant `@start_date` to change each row

And now you have a list with 1000 days starting with `@start_date`

Last you filter using `@end_date` to remove dates bigger than the one you want.

Comment: Yep, I know about the end date stuff. I had actually taken it out while playing with the formula, while I was playing around with the equation part trying to understand it.

Comment: so what part you you still dont understand?

Comment: No, I got it now. Your explanation was great. I guess I just didn't think about how it was creating a three column table with the joins. Each row is just the three columns combined, with the multiplication where necessary. Once that clicked, the formula made a lot of sense. Thanks