# interpolating missing values in a table in Access VBA

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, vba

I have an Access function that exports a table of values to Excel, in the following format.

```
ID  CurveShortName  MarkRunID MarkDate ZeroCurveID MaturityDate ZeroRate    DiscountFactor
15  CAD Sovereign   10091   7/2/2015    15-10091    7/2/2015    0.007499923 1
15  CAD Sovereign   10091   7/2/2015    15-10091    7/3/2015    0.007499923 0.999979452
15  CAD Sovereign   10091   7/2/2015    15-10091    7/5/2015    0.00899634  0.999186963
15  CAD Sovereign   10091   7/2/2015    15-10091    7/6/2015    0.008993128 0.998473566
```

etc.

there are some dates missing from the MaturityDate column (like 7/4/2015, for example) and I want to interpolate this value using all the values associated with the same MarkDate (which would be 7/2/2015).

how do I interpolate between values in Access? I have a function that I use for Excel VBA, but I am struggling to convert it to Access VBA. I was thinking of setting up something beginning with

```
Function CurveInterpolateRecordset(rsCurve As Recordset, InterpDate As Date) As Double
```

so that I could directly interpolate using a given curve and date, but I cant get it working.

Comment: How will you identify the missing dates? Does "interpolate" mean an average of known values or something else?

Comment: yeah by interpolate I just mean a linear interpolation of the known values in the ZeroRate column - so for 7/4/2015 it would just take the average of 7/3/2015 and 7/5/2015.

I am not sure how to identify the missing dates; I was thinking about making another column with the complete set of dates to use as a reference, and then whenever the MaturityDate column doesn't match the reference column, it can interpolate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a plain SQL solution. Is made with `SQL server` but all function should be found in `ACCESS`

- [IIF](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/iif.php)
- [DATEDIFF](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/datediff.php)

### Description

1. I create a simplify version of your table for source to create the interpolation
2. I create a table `allDates` where you can store all dates available, this allow found the missing dates. There are [**functions**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32639361/sql-date-comparison-only-comparing-years/32639585#32639585) to create that table very easy.
3. Create table `rangesInter` This calculate the ranges, if range is `>1 day` you have missing dates. In that case save the `startRate` and the `changeRate` for interpolation.

   - After finish I realize this query could also be include direct in the select, the same way I create the `(min , max)` table.
4. Join all tables together, result is the first 3 columns but I leave all so you can check where the date came.

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d5a5c/6)**

```
   SELECT 
       IIF(i.MarkDate IS NULL, r.MarkDate, i.MarkDate) as MarkDate,
       a.MaturityDate,
       IIF(
           i.ZeroRate IS NULL,
           r.startRate + DATEDIFF ( day , r.begindate, a.MaturityDate ) * rateChange,
           i.ZeroRate
          ) as ZeroRate, -- use values from r to interpolate rate
       i.*, r.*
   FROM  allDates a
   left Join Inter I
    on a.MaturityDate  = I.MaturityDate
   cross join
    (SELECT MIN(MaturityDate) minDate, MAX(MaturityDate) maxDate
     FROM Inter) as t
   left join rangesInter r
     on a.MaturityDate > r.[begindate]
    and a.MaturityDate < r.[enddate] 
   where a.MaturityDate >= t.minDate
     and a.MaturityDate <= t.maxDate;
```

Comment: My recomendation start simple and one piece each time.

Comment: hey thank you, I appreciate your help. do you know how I would go about porting this kind of function into Access? using the strSQL function does not seem to work for large sections of SQL code.

Comment: What is strSQL function? I think this should work in access, as I say try to build your query one piece at each time.

Comment: in your solution 

"  IIF(i.MarkDate IS NULL, r.MarkDate, i.MarkDate) as MarkDate,
           a.MaturityDate,  "

what is the difference between "r.MarkDate" and "i.MarkDate"?

Comment: If you check the fiddle demo, in each row one MarkDate is null and the other isnt. One side is your data, the other is the interpolated data. So if one is null I use the other.

Comment: ah okay I see, thank you so much. I have gone through the demo and I think I understand what you have done. when you refer to some variables as "I2.[MarkDate]" or "I1.[MaturityDate]", what does the "I1" do?

Comment: when I use the table `inter` i create an alias `I`, Here -> `left Join Inter I` that way code become easy to read because shorter names.

Comment: is the SQL fiddle demo still working for you? I can't seem to open it anymore.

Comment: Yes, looks like is down now. Just give it some time and will be available again. That is why beside the fiddle always post the SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code to identify missing values:

[Find missing values](http://www.devx.com/dbzone/Article/40345)

while the code in the download on page 2 shows how to find missing dates:

[Find missing dates](http://www.devx.com/dbzone/Article/40345/0/page/2)

Having those, you would - as Varun states - use linear interpolation to calculate the missing measurements.